# React Document upload with chunking facility

Tags: reactjs, plupload

Sorry for asking generic question.

So, we are looking for some library / NPM Package which will support

1. Document upload with Button and Drag and Drop.
2. Chunking document post call (Need to support large size document hence important).
3. Pl upload, is one of the option, however noticed it is not frequently getting updated.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [react-uploady](https://github.com/rpldy/react-uploady)

1. It has components for [button](https://github.com/rpldy/react-uploady/blob/master/packages/ui/upload-button) and [drag&drop](https://github.com/rpldy/react-uploady/blob/master/packages/ui/upload-drop-zone)
2. It supports [chunked uploads](https://github.com/rpldy/react-uploady/blob/master/packages/ui/chunked-uploady)

It has hooks to manage upload lifecycle and other useful functionality (ex: abort, retry)

- not sure what you mean by #3 "Pl upload"

Comment: Pl upload is a library which allows chunking while document upload, however its pretty old and does not get frequent updates. Thanks for answer, do we have any more alternatives..?